# NSColor colorwithpatternimage paints NSView in black color

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, background-color, nscolor

I'm creating a `NSColor` using `colorWithPatternImage` as it shown in Apple example:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        backgrColor = [[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"greenfelt"]] retain];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [backgrColor set];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}
```

The image is taken from the same example and it works there. When I try it in my application, the view is colored in black. Why can it be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not finding the image, most likely because you're not using an extension on the filename.

*Update:* A quick test confirms that omitting the extension should still work.  But it still may not be finding the image.  Maybe it wasn't added to the project or you mistyped the name? Also, I assume that this view is actually being created using -initWithFrame:, right?

Comment: Thanks for response. This view is created through IB and bound to the according IBOutlet in the my subclass of NSViewController. Adding the extension indeed helped, but I found also another problem that prevented the image from being found. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: @NavaCarmon, what was the other problem?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but my guess is that my application is built from bundles and the whole thing was to get the resource from proper bundle...